# match divs by id and delete content inside that

Tags: javascript

I have couple of divs like

```
<div id="rg_dia_0">
          zdszczxvzxvzxvc
</div>
<div id="rg_dia_1">
          dfgdZXcZC
</div>
<div id="rg_dia_2">
          hfhgjhgjdj
</div>
```

I need javascript to fetch all the divs and delete the content. I think we can use regex to match the ids as only the number that is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by *Sam* in Javascript it can be

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
 document.getElementById("rg_dia_" + i).innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
 $("#rg_dia_" + i).html("");
}
```

to clarify; the above obviously requires the use of jQuery, as l.devries so blatantly down-voted as an act of true adulthood and surely not be considered as trolling since the explanation as of why had to be requested first. glad to have people like you on-board!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this can easily be done with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  I would strongly encourage you to learn it.

```
$('div').each(function() {
    $(this).html('');
});
$('#id').html(newContent);
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
$("div[id^='rg_dia_']").html("");
```

see [this](http://www.emadibrahim.com/2009/07/25/jquery-wildcard-selector/) for wildcard attribute selection in jQuery.

Comment: why down-vote? no grudges, but I want to know what needs to be corrected.

Comment: `$ is not defined`; javascript != jquery